# Android Gesture - onDown is called only sometimes

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

This is my first time working with Android gestures. I'm trying to call swipeRight() and swipeLeft() using the following method I found on this site.

**SwipeTouchListener.java**

```
public class SwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public SwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        return true;
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {

    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {

    }

    private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

        private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (distanceX > 0)
                    onSwipeRight();
                else
                    onSwipeLeft();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And in my Activity, I call the following method and override the onSwipeLeft() and onSwipeRight() and show a Toast message on both.

```
chartFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeTouchListener(this){

    @Override
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Swipe Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Swipe Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

But the problem is, I only see the toast messages on very few occasions. I put a breakpoint in onDown method and found out, it only gets called a few times (like once in 20 maybe).

EDIT : I called this method on a ViewFlipper.

EDIT 2 : I am showing a pie chart and a bar chart in the ViewFlipper as 2 views. I just found out that swiping over the charts doesn't register as a touch. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

in your method

```
 @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
            if (distanceX > 0)
                onSwipeRight();
            else
                onSwipeLeft();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

you have AND condition for distance covered by user should be greater than the SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD distance which might not true in every case and you have another AND condition for SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD in many cases this could be lower than the threshold value.So you are seeing results only in the cases distance is more than the threshold and velocity is also more than the threshold velocity try to lower these values and you will see results more often